# ORA-03113 after running INSERT ALL through Delphi

Tags: database, delphi, oracle10g

I am trying to insert multiple records into Oracle Database on a single table through Delphi application code using the following query:

INSERT ALL 
INTO PROJECT (f1, f2) VALUES (v1, v2)
INTO PROJECT (f1, f2) VALUES (v3, v4)
INTO PROJECT (f1, f2) VALUES (v5, v6)
SELECT * FROM DUAL

I add the above query statement to my Delphi query and run qry.ExecSql. The execution happens fine for the first time, and I see that the records get added into the table, but when the same code runs for the next query, I receive the exception: ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please post your Delphi code.

Answer (score 1):

Often the ora-03113 error is the last in a series of errors reported.  Can you debug the code and see if other errors are reported?  Also, what components are you using for your connection and query objects?  There are a number of different options in Delphi, so the answer could be dbGo, dbExpress, FireDAC, or a third party component set.  You may want to test your statement using SQLPlus or another tool.  If so, make sure the tool is using the same Oracle Home that your Delphi components are using.  Sometimes 3113 errors are caused by using an older Oracle Client against a newer Oracle Server, you may want to check the versions.

Comment: I realized that I am getting the error since i am passing a blob field as parameter in my next INSERT ALL statement. That gives the exception. Is it possible that one is not allowed to pass blob as parameters in INSERT ALL?

Comment: It should be allowed.  Could you post the code?  You could also test using a normal insert statement and your parameter blob code (that will tell you if the problem is really "insert all".

Answer (score 1):

For detail exception log, look into "alert.log" file

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I get the exception OSD-04500: illegal option specified O/S-Error: (OS 1) Incorrect function. ! This happens because i am passing blob as parameter in my query. How can I work around this?

Comment: It's better to insert record with empty_blob() value, then fetch new row locator and update blob. To pass blob try to use `qQuery.ParamByName('Blob_field_name').LoadFromStream(AStream, ftBLOB);`